# Development Pod can't import module from dependency Pod if its a .framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, firebase, cocoapods, podspec

I've created a pod with  `pod lib create ASAuthFramework`, add the dependency in .podspec: `s.dependency 'ReactiveCocoa'`, updated an example project pod (with only ASAuthFramework) and I could import ReactiveCocoa module: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbm4Q.png). Then I added a new dependency: `s.dependency 'Firebase/Auth'`, updated example project's pod and I could NOT import a FirebaseAuth module to development pod, but I could do it in an Example project's ViewController: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT5nD.png). Any ideas?

I've created project with that problem:
repo: github.com/anekk/DVPodAuth.git

run from Example's root: `pod install`
then open .xcworkspace

Comment: No, the problem still exist. I've created an issue at pods github but it was closed because noone answered!